# ¿Como redirijo de un jsp a otro con un anchor tag?

Tags: java, html5, jsp

[image: Imagen]

Para poder actualizar o update una base de datos se usar este

Comment: Deberías enviar tu petición al Servlet añadiendo el `id` del registro que quieres editar en la URL `/guards/update/<id>` y en el Servlet consultar por ese ID, añadirlo a la respuesta y redirigir hacia la vista de edición con los valores del registro a editar. Por ejemplo: `<input type="text" value="${guard.nombre}"/>`.

Comment: guzgarcia entonces me recomiendas hacer un "SELECT" del <id> para poder seleccionar algunos de los usuarios o cual seria la manera más facil o que me recomindes hacerlo

Comment: El flujo es sencillo: La url debe ser algo como `"/guards/update/${guard.id}"`. En el servlet, recuperas ese id y consultas a la base de datos para traer el `guard` con dicho id. Una vez recuperado, añades el `guard` a la respuesta y rediriges hacia la vista `edit.jsp`. Ésta vista tendrá un formulario con inputs, selects o lo que sea donde deben estar precargados con los datos del `guard` a editar. Así, en el input nombre, el valor predefinido debe ser `${guard.nombre}`. De ésta manera, cuando el documento se renderice verás los valores actuales del `guard`.